# WebApi Call from BackgroundTask in RunTime Component UWP Windows 10 App

Tags: c#, uwp, background-task

I am successfully able to call the Web Api deployed on below link from mobile app or console app.
https://dposapi.azurewebsites.net/DPosApi/v1/Configurations/GetAll

Problem is that when i put this call in BackgroundTask in a RunTime Component project and triggers the background task from mobile app than execution hangs on the line of code where i am calling the Web Api. Sample is available on below link.

https://github.com/imranshabbir/Sample

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your run method should be async, like this: (note the await before FillProducts() )

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
        BackgroundTaskDeferral deferal = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        // do your task here
        await FillProducts();
        deferal.Complete();
}
```

Btw. are you sure that the

> "execution hangs on the line of code where i am calling the Web Api"

?

In your current code the problem is that the background task is finished before you get the results (without the await the execution hits the `deferal.Complete();` line earlier). So in that case you just don't see the results, but that should not be a hang.

But anyway... async/await is the answer.

Comment: This code showing me error **Cannot await void**.Please Help me. @gregkalapos

Comment: That's because your method is void. Make it return a Task.